# Pagination in html

Tags: html, pagination

I know Pagination works like this

```
<head>
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />
<title>My article, page 2</title>
</head>
```

but can Pagination be used to automatically pick "prev" and "next" references based on the current html page, So that I basically dont have to hardcode the href value ?

Comment: Did you accidentally press enter before you finished typing the question?

Comment: Yes, but not with plain HTML. You need to use the server-side language that creates the link tags as well.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20pagination

Comment: Does this require a javascript then ?